# How is lazy evaluation implemented (in ORMs for example)

Tags: python, activerecord, orm

Im curious to know how lazy evaluation is implemented at higher levels, ie in libraries, etc. For example, how does the Django ORM or ActiveRecord defer evaluation of query until it is actually used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's have a look at some methods for django's [`django.db.models.query.QuerySet`](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/query.py) class:

```
class QuerySet(object):
    """
    Represents a lazy database lookup for a set of objects.
    """
    def __init__(self, model=None, query=None, using=None):
        ...
        self._result_cache = None
        ...

     def __len__(self):
        if self._result_cache is None:
          ...
        elif self._iter:
          ...
        return len(self._result_cache)

    def __iter__(self):
        if self._result_cache is None:
          ...
        if self._iter:
          ...
        return iter(self._result_cache)

    def __nonzero__(self):
        if self._result_cache is not None:
          ...

    def __contains__(self, val):
        if self._result_cache is not None:
          ...
        else:
          ...
        ...

    def __getitem__(self, k):
        ...
        if self._result_cache is not None:
        ...
        ...
```

The pattern that these methods follow is that no queries are executed until some method that really needs to return some result is called. At that point, the result is stored in `self._result_cache` and any subsequent call to the same method returns the cached value.

Comment: Thanks! I was too lazy to go digging around github :)

Answer (score 6):

In Python, one object may "exist" - but its intrinsic value will only be known by the outer world at the moment it is used with one of the operators - since the operators are defined in the class by the magic names with double underscores, if a class writes the appropriate code to execute the deferred code when the operator is called, it is just fine.

That means, if the object's value is, for example, to be used like a string, any part of the program that will use the object will call, at some point, the "__str__" coercion method.

For example, let's create an object that behaves like a string, but tells the current time. Strings can be concatenated to other strings(__add__), can have their length requested (__len__), and so on. If we want it to fit perfectly in the place of a string, we'd have to override all methods. The idea is to retrieve the actual value just when one of the operators is called - otherwise, the actual object can freely be assigned to variables, and passed around. It will only be evaluated when its value is needed

Then, one can have some code like this:

```
class timestr(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = None
    def __str__(self):
        self._getvalue()
        return self.value
    def __len__(self):
        self._getvalue()
        return len(self.value)
    def __add__(self, other):
        self._getvalue()
        return self.value + other
    def _getvalue(self):
        timet = time.localtime()
        self.value = " %s:%s:%s " % (timet.tm_hour, timet.tm_min, timet.tm_sec)
```

And using it on the console, you may have:

```
>>> a = timestr()
>>> b = timestr()
>>> print b
 17:16:22 
>>> print a
 17:16:25
```

If the value for which you want a lazy evaluation is an attribute of your object (like Peson.name ) instead of what your object actually behaves like - it is even easier. Because Python allows all object attributes to be of a special type - called a descriptor -- which actually has a method called each time the attribute will be accessed. Therefore, one just has to create a class with a proper method named `__get__` to fetch the actual value. This method will be called only when the attribute is needed.

Python even has an utility for easy descriptor creation - the "property"  keyword, that makes this even easier - you pass a method that is the code to generate the attribute as the first parameter to property.

So, having an Event class with a lazy (and live) evaluated time, is just a matter of writting:

```
import time

class Event(object):
    @property
    def time(self):
        timet = time.localtime()
        return " %s:%s:%s " % (timet.tm_hour, timet.tm_min, timet.tm_sec)
```

And use it as in:

```
>>> e= Event()
>>> e.time
' 17:25:8 '
>>> e.time
' 17:25:10 '
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. The only reason i marked the other as the answer is because the poster referenced the actual library I asked about.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the specifics about which library you talking about but, from an algorithm standpoint, I've always used/undertsood it as follows: (psuedo code from a python novice)

```
class Object:

    #... Other stuff ...

    _actual_property = None;

    def interface():
        if _actual_property is None:
            # Execute query and load up _actual_property

        return _actual_property
```

Essentially because the interface and implementation are separated, you can define behaviors to execute upon request.

Comment: Small nitpick: if `None` is returned by the lazily evaluated computation, this will reevaluate the query every time `interface()` is called.

Comment: that's assuming it's possible that the Evaluation would (or could) return `None`, I believe it's obvious I'm simply trying to present the concept... not production code.

Comment: The question is about Python's transparent ways to do this

Comment: The algorithm is quite obvious. I was asking from more of an implementation perspective.

Answer (score 1):

The mechanism is quite simple:

```
class Lazy:
    def __init__(self, evaluate):
        self.evaluate = evaluate
        self.computed = False
    def getresult(self):
        if not self.computed:
            self.result = self.evaluate()
            self.computed = True
        return self.result
```

Then, this utility can be used as:

```
def some_computation(a, b):
    return ...

# bind the computation to its operands, but don't evaluate it yet.
lazy = Lazy(lambda: some_computation(1, 2))

# "some_computation()" is evaluated now.
print lazy.getresult()

# use the cached result again without re-computing.
print lazy.getresult()
```

This implementation uses callables to represent the computation, but there are many variations on this theme (e.g. a base class that requires you to imlement an `evaluate()` method, etc.).