# simulating django settings to retrieve from database, values getting cached

Tags: python, django

am trying to simulate django's settings file. Where I've built a model to host some of the settings where it can be changed by admin. The concepts works fine, but its acting strange when the value is changed the code is not picking up the new changes.

Here is my core_settings

```
class CoreSettings(object):
    def __getattr__(self, item):
        try:
            return Configuration.objects.get(key=item).value
        except Configuration.DoesNotExist :
            return getattr(settings, item)

core_settings = CoreSettings()
```

am basically using the above as follows

```
SF_PUBLICATION_PAGINATION_PP = int(getattr(core_settings, 'SF_PUBLICATION_PAGINATION_PP'))
```

SF_PUBLICATION_PAGINATION_PP is getting the correct value from the Configuration model, but when I update the field value its not reflected. Only when I alter the file causing it to recompile where am getting the changes..

Any ideas?

---

update:

it seems like am seeing the changes only when the runserver is refreshed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the value of your setting is not being refreshed, because its value is set when your settings.py is 'loaded', which happen when e.g you do 'runserver' in a dev enviroment.

So, you can deal with, doing something like this:

```
def get_live_setting(key):
try:
    return Configuration.objects.get(key=key).value
except Configuration.DoesNotExist :
    return getattr(settings, key)

# get SF_PUBLICATION_PAGINATION_PP's value
get_live_setting('SF_PUBLICATION_PAGINATION_PP')
```

with this you can solve your problem, but the correct way is using lazy evaluation, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976103/how-is-lazy-evaluation-implemented-in-orms-for-example) some samples and [here](http://theorangeduck.com/page/lazy-python) a funny post about 'lazy-python'.

Comment: Hi trinchet, thanks for the help.. The example you gave works, but how would I adapt it into a class form instead of a function?

Comment: Yes, you can do that too, and it is more elegant right? ;-), but you can't force evaluation doing something like this `int(getattr(core_settings, 'SF_PUBLICATION_PAGINATION_PP'))`, note that int() implicates evaluation at the moment you are defining it, take a look to the links around lazy evaluation i wrote you, undoubtedly you will found there your best solution.

Answer (score 1):

What about using a package designed for this purpose?

Have a look at: [`django-livesettings`](http://django-livesettings.readthedocs.org/en/latest/about.html)

Even if you decide not to use it, you can always have a look at how it's done there!

---

Regarding your specific issue. how do you update the field value? Are you sure the value is retrieved from the database and not from your `except` clause?

Comment: hi thomas, i went through django-livesettings and i couldn't see difference in the __getattr__ function we both using. Yeah, I did debugging and am not seeing the value from the except, am seeing the cached value from Configuration model